# Implementing service worker in existing ASP.NET Core MVC application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core MVC web application where I have these two tasks that should be running as background services:

1. Set the user status as "Expired" if EndOfSubscription date is == DateTime.Now
2. Before 1 month of EndOfSubscription date send a reminder e-mail to this user

After searching, I found that I can use service worker to implement this. But I'm totally confused how to use this service worker in existing ASP.NET Core MVC web application where I need to access my models and database.

Should I isolate these tasks in a separate service worker project? But in this case should I share the same database for both projects?

Can someone guide me with main steps in this kind of situations?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just add a BackgroundService as the docs show. There's nothing special to a "service worker", it's just a call do `services.AddHostedService`

Comment: Service Workers are part of the [Service Worker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API), which is JavaScript. I'm not sure why you'd want a separate project for that. You may want to add some API endpoints for the worker to call. I would suggest finding some tutorials on creating them. They do run in the browser, so it might not be the best solution to your issue.

Comment: @HereticMonkey the question isn't about Javascript. The OP used the wrong tag

Comment: If you create a new "service worker' application you'll see it does nothing more than register some services with `AddHostedService`. Those services will start running when the GenericHost/WebHost starts running

Comment: You shouldn't compare equality to `DateTime.Now`. A `DateTime` is accurate to the ticket (0.0001 milliseconds), so you have a very slim chance of that line of code running at the exact correct millisecond. It'd be better to do something like `Set the user status as "Expired" if EndOfSubscription date is <= DateTime.Now`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's certainly an opinion of what the OP wants, and I see you've altered the question to match your interpretation.

Comment: @HereticMonkey no I haven't. The text wasn't changed at all. There's no interpretation either. The OP clearly asks about `an ASP.NET Core MVC web application` with tasks `running as background services`. If you check the tag (which I added) you'll see this refers to [ASP.NET Core Background Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) and the [worker service](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/what-are-dotnet-worker-services) template, which has nothing to do with Javascript

Comment: @HereticMonkey if you cared to see the question's edit history you'd see that Marc Gravell fixed the casing and I only added the tag. If you feel this is about Javascript, feel free to add the tags you prefer

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I stopped caring about this question two hours ago, not sure why you're still pinging me about it. I see an edit by a "marc_s", who I don't believe is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell. In any case, again, I don't really care. There are plenty of more interesting questions about.

Answer (score 7):

[Service worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) or [Worker service](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/what-are-dotnet-worker-services)?

- A Service Worker is a way to run background tasks *in a browser* and definitely unsuitable if you want to execute something on the server.
- A Worker service is essentially a template with the (few) calls needed to run a BackgroundService/IHostedService in a console application and (optionally, through extensions) as a Linux daemon or Windows service. You don't need that template to create and run a BackgroundService.

The tutorial [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) shows how to create and use a BackgroundService but is a bit ... overengineered. The article tries to show too many things at the same time and ends up missing some essential things.

A better introduction is Steve Gordon's [What are Worker Services?](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/what-are-dotnet-worker-services).

**The background service**

All that's needed to create a background service, is a class that implements the [IHostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) interface. Instead of implementing all the interface methods, it's easier to inherit from the [BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) base class and override just the `ExecuteAsync` method.

The article's example shows this method doesn't need to be anything fancy:

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

That's just a loop with a delay. This will run until the web app terminates and signals the `stoppingToken`. This service will be created by the DI container, so it can have service dependencies like `ILogger` or any other singleton service.

**Registering the service**

The background service needs to be registered as a service in `ConfigureServices`, the same way any other service is registered. If you have a console application, you configure it in the host's `ConfigureServices` call. If you have a web application, you need to register it in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddDbContext<OrdersContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        
        ...

        //Register the service
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();

        services.AddRazorPages();
    }
```

This registers `Worker` as a service that can be constructed by the DI container *and* adds it to the list of hosted services that will start once `.Run()` is called in the web app's `Main` :

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}
```

**Using DbContext and other scoped services**

Adding a DbContext as a dependency is trickier, since `DbContext` is a scoped service. We can't just inject a `DbContext` instance and store it in a field - a DbContext is meant to be used as a Unit-of-Work, something that collects all changes made for a single scenario and either commit all of them to the database or discard them. It's meant to be used inside a `using` block. If we dispose the single `DbContext` instance we injected though, where do we get a new one?

To solve this, we have to inject the DI service, `IServiceProvider`, create a scope explicitly and get our DbContext from this scope:

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

    private readonly IServiceProvider _services;

    //Inject IServiceProvider
    public Worker(IServiceProvider services, ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _services=services;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            //Create the scope
            using (var scope = _services.CreateScope())
            {
                //Create OrdersContext in the scope
                var ctx = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<OrdersContext>();
                
                var latestOrders = await ctx.Orders
                                            .Where(o=>o.Created>=DateTime.Today)
                                            .ToListAsync();
                //Make some changes
                if (allOK)
                {
                    await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
            }
            //OrdersContext will be disposed when exiting the scope
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The `OrdersContext` will be disposed when the scope exits and any unsaved changes will be discarded.

Nothing says the entire code needs to be inside `ExecuteAsync`. Once the code starts getting too long, we can easily extract the important code into a separate method :

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);

        using (var scope = _services.CreateScope())
        {
            var ctx = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<OrdersContext>();
            await DoWorkAsync(ctx,stoppingToken);
        }

        await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
    }
}

private async Task DoWorkAsync(OrdersContext ctx,CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    var latestOrders = await ctx.Orders
                                .Where(o=>o.Created>=DateTime.Today)
                                .ToListAsync();
    //Make some changes
    if (allOK)
    {
        await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```