# How to link woker background service to the ASP MVC REST API endpoint

Tags: asp.net-core, worker-service

I create api project and worker service project into same project solution. (FYI : these project have separate startup.cs and program.cs files, it's running in mutiple projects)
so i want to link worker service  into endpoint and worker service return result set into the api controller endpoint

Comment: you should put your business logic into a class library that both the API Controller and worker use

Comment: Maybe you can refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64213111/implementing-service-worker-in-existing-asp-net-core-mvc-application